# Cannot use icon in my object. It throws TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, modal-dialog, icons

I am working on a add ticket modal where I have added a couple fields and some dropdown menus. I want to add different color depending on the severity or status. I am able to add the colors dynamically but I cannot do the same with color box that I want to display in front of the box.

Sorry I am new to Stackoverflow and might have missed adding a few details, please let me know what specific details needed to added.

Update: The library I used for dropdown is react-select.

[image: Reference Image]

```
const data = getLocalData(MASTER_DATA);

  const getPriorityDropdownOption = (element) => {
    return {
      label: <div>{element.value}</div>,
      value: element.id,
    };
  };

const getDropdownOption = (element) => {
    return {
      label: <div>{element.value}</div>,
      value: element.id,


      // bg: <BsSquareFill className="text-[#FFFF00] capitalize" />,
      **// I want to make this icon work dynamically, like below example.**
      
      // bg: <BsSquareFill className={`"text-[${element.color}] capitalize"`} />
      

      color: "#fff",
    };
  };

const initializeDropdownValues = () => {
    var tempDropdownOptions = { ...dropdownOptions };
    if (isExists(data)) {
      if (isExists(data.priority)) {
        let arr = data.priority.map(function (element) {
          return getPriorityDropdownOption(element);
        });
        tempDropdownOptions.filterPriorityOptions = arr;
      }

      if (isExists(data.severity)) {
        let arr = data.severity.map(function (element) {
          return getDropdownOption(element);
        });
        tempDropdownOptions.filterSeverityOptions = arr;
      }

      if (isExists(data.status)) {
        let arr = data.status.map(function (element) {
          return getDropdownOption(element);
        });
        tempDropdownOptions.filterStatusOptions = arr;
      }
      setDropdownOptions(tempDropdownOptions);
    }
  };

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("dropdownOptions-->", dropdownOptions);
  }, [dropdownOptions]);
```

Comment: What component do you use for the select? Based on the error message, it look lite the component only supports strings as bg. I would guess that the bg property is for the background color?

Comment: @Disco I am using react-select library. And yeah, bg property is for background color.

Comment: They have a example for that in the documentation
https://react-select.com/styles#cx-and-custom-components

Comment: I did try to make sense of it, but couldn't. How can I make changes to my code so that it can accept the icon as the value?